# How to find and click on an option inside a combobox where all classes have the same name

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Good morning guys.
I'm having trouble locating an element within a web page through selenium. Below is the code I'm using and also the html of the page. I don't know where I'm going wrong because I can't find the combo box element and then click on it.

[image]

I'm using this code, but I also tried to do a web scrapping to see if the elements were correct, but the returned value is only 0

```
test1 = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'el-select-dropdown__wrap el-scrollbar__wrap')#DIV
test2 = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'el-scrollbar__view el-select-dropdown__list') #Ul class
op_unitaria = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'el-select-dropdown__item') # opção unitario
op_unitaria01 = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'el-select-dropdown__item') #lista com todas as opções

valor = op_unitaria01[30].get_attribute("value")
print(valor)
valor1 = op_unitaria01[100].get_property("value")
print(valor1)
print(valor1.text)
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Please do not share the HTML in the form of image, share it in the form of text.

Comment: please add enough details such as the URL so that others can try to help

Comment: Go based on index of element in `find_elements()` or search element based on text

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui resolver utilizando o find_elements e localizando cada elemento com o indice.
Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui resolver utilizando o find_elements e localizando cada elemento com o indice.